# Taylor series $\frac 1{1+z^2}$ about $z = 2$

Tags: complex-analysis

So we want to find the Taylor series of $\frac 1{1+z^2}$ about $z = 2$. First and foremost the radius of convergence is $\sqrt 5$ since the distance from $\pm i$ to $z = 2$ is $\sqrt 5$.

But how can we go about finding the Taylor series in terms of $z - 2$ without having to compute a bunch of derivatives? I tried partial fractions but the terms were no easier to work with. I'm sure there should be a somewhat effective way to approach this.

Comment: it's almost the same than $z\mapsto \arctan(z)$ around $z=2$

Comment: Right but the series of arctan(z) around z = 2 is not trivial. If it was then sure we could just have differentiated.

Comment: What partial fractions did you get? If $y=z-2$ then $1+z^2=(z+i)(z-i)=(y+2+i)(y+2-i)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{1+z^2}=\frac{1}{(z-i)(z+i)}=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{z-i}-\frac{1}{z+i}\right)=\\=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{z-2+2-i}-\frac{1}{z-2+2+i}\right)=\\=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{\frac{1}{-2+i}}{\frac{z-2}{-2+i}-1}-\frac{\frac{1}{-2-i}}{\frac{z-2}{-2-i}-1}\right)$$

Now you can use formula for geometric series:

$$\frac{1}{1-y}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}y^n$$

Comment: Thanks. Is it true that the radius of convergence becomes $\sqrt 5$? Since the distance in the complex plane from $\pm i$ to $z = 2$ is $\sqrt 5$.

Comment: The radius $\sqrt{5}$ in my solution comes form $|2-i|=\sqrt{5}$.